# How to implement validation with jQuery on a asp.Net submit button?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate, submit

I want to call some web-service webmethods on asp.net submit button's click in order to validate the form regarding to some business logic and then I would like to have the button to go on its default behavior if the validation is OK.

How can I stop the aspx page to post-back (after submit button click) and continue submitting the form only if it is allowed by the 'success' function of jQuery.ajax()'s option parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass [Form Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) Callback to ajax function. If ajax executes successfully, your form submit callback will be called and form will be submitted. Otherwise, not

For ex, submit button code could look like this

```
function submitWithValidation() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(){
        $('form').submit();
      }
    });

    return false;
}
```

The button will stop submitting form. If validation succeeds, ajax success will submit the form, otherwise  invalid form will stay with client

Comment: So this is the 'onclick' attribute of the button in this case?

Comment: No, this is onclientclick - function on javascript. Look at edited code